# Get width of button Javascript without the "px"

Tags: javascript, html, button, width

I have some code that gets the width of a button, but it always returns the width of the button with "px" on the end. Is there an easy way (without creating a function that removes the last two characters) of getting the width without the "px" part, but still in pixels?

[jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/XdADS/)

```
<button name="test" id="mybutton" onclick="alert(this.style.width);" style="width:200px;">Click me</button>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Hey a quick a simple answer for this is to use parseInt on the number

```
<button name="test" id="mybutton" onclick="alert(parseInt(this.style.width,10));" style="width:200px;">Click me</button>
```

See the fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/XdADS/6/

Comment: Always pass the second parameter to `parseInt`.

Comment: Good point it defaults to 10 but you are correct that its best practice to include it, so ive updated my answer.

Comment: you misplaced the closing parentheses, and i can't edit cause it's less than 6 characters ><

Comment: Actually it defaults to "guess". For instance, `parseInt("0x10")` returns 16, whereas `parseInt("0x10",10)` returns 0. In some browsers, numbers that start with `0` are considered octal, like `parseInt("010")` will return 8.

Answer (score 5):

You could chuck a replace at the end?

```
<button name="test" id="mybutton" onclick="alert(this.style.width.replace('px', ''));" style="width:200px;">Click me</button>
```

Bare in mind that if you have the width in em's, rem's or percentage etc... this will give you the CSS declare size e.g. 12 for 12em instead of the actual size, you would need to use something like this otherwise:

```
this.offsetWidth
```

Answer (score 4):

Use  [`parseInt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)

```
onclick="alert(parseInt(this.style.width,10));
```

[**Fiddle Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/XdADS/5/)

Comment: This is correct. You should always pass in the radix, especially if you want it to lint correctly.

Answer (score 2):

Correct Code:

```
<button name="test" id="mybutton" onclick="alert(this.style.width.replace('px',''));" style="width:200px;">Click me</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

if the width is NOT explicitly declared, then the only choice is to use:

```
id_of_btn.offsetWidth
```

according to the w3school, offsetWidth: "Returns the width of an element, including padding, border and scrollbar"

source: https://www.w3schools.com/jsreF/dom_obj_all.asp

Answer (score -3):

You could use jQuery's [`width()`](http://api.jquery.com/width/) function to achieve this.